# Create a mirror to reflect objects for vfx compositing

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, reflection, shadowcatcher

I would like to create a virtual mirror to compose on top of a real mirror to reflect objects in Blender.

This is how I imagined it in my mind: (The mirror completely reflects the object but leaves the original real reflection)

[image: The mirror completely reflects the object but leaves the original real reflection]

But when I try to do it, it looks like this: (the reflection is dark, transparent, and barely visible)

[image: the reflection is dark and slightly transparent]

I'm probably not doing this the right way: I'm creating a glossy plane and setting it as a shadow catcher in the visibility part of the object properties. I couldn't find instructions about this anywhere, so I'm just guessing...

Comment: Hello :). I'm no expert on mirrors, but wouldn't multiple view layers work better? Then you could choose what exactly to reflect and just composite it on top.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a beginner. How does that work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reflection in mirror](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165520/reflection-in-mirror)

Comment: @Luciano I don't think so, I'm trying to put the reflection on top of an image of a mirror. Or maybe a better explanation would be, i want to create a mirror, where the reflection is visible (and not transparent) but the mirror it self is completely transparent. Basically like a shadow catcher, but for reflections.

Comment: @brockmann I think that might be it, it seems  very advanced, especially for a beginner like me. But I will try it tomorrow

Comment: Not really advanced, just a bit of work since cycles is a pathtracer... Recommend try that and keep us posted so we can vote to re-open the post in case.

Comment: @brockmann well, its advanced compared to what knowledge I have. But yeah i will try it.